# Event Receiver Update List

Tags: event-receivers

I have a list (A) which contains these fields: `Software`, `Quantity`, `Used`, and `Available`. Fields `Used` and `Available` are hidden fields. Then I have another list (B) which contains a lookup field (Software) from list (A). I created a COUNT lookup field in list(A) to count the total of software used in list (B). What I want to accomplish is to create an event receiver to do the calculation and update fields Used and Available. How can I achieve this?